# Best way to remove ANSI color escapes in Unix

Tags: perl, unix

I have a perl progaram its prints output with color. if I rediect the output in the file and open it in vi I see color special character.
something like this.

```
^[[31;43mAnd this is red on_yellow too^[[0m
```

What is the best way to remove this color character from the output file?

Thanks

Update:

I tried thid regex. it works for me:

```
 cat -v a|head
^[[30;41mThis is black on_red^[[0m
^[[30;41mAnd this is black on_red too^[[0m
^[[30;42mThis is black on_green^[[0m
^[[30;42mAnd this is black on_green too^[[0m
^[[30;43mThis is black on_yellow^[[0m
^[[30;43mAnd this is black on_yellow too^[[0m
^[[30;44mThis is black on_blue^[[0m
^[[30;44mAnd this is black on_blue too^[[0m
^[[30;45mThis is black on_magenta^[[0m
^[[30;45mAnd this is black on_magenta too^[[0m


$ cat -v a|head|perl -lane 's/\^\[\[\d+(;\d+)*m//g; print'
This is black on_red
And this is black on_red too
This is black on_green
And this is black on_green too
This is black on_yellow
And this is black on_yellow too
This is black on_blue
And this is black on_blue too
This is black on_magenta
And this is black on_magenta too
```

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4527/program-that-passes-stdin-to-stdout-with-color-codes-stripped

Comment: if you just want to view it use `less -R`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Coincidentally I just had to solve this problem, and this is the regexp I came up with:

```
while (<>) {
    s/\e\[[\d;]*[a-zA-Z]//g;
    print;
}
```

I just derived this by examining some example output (in particular, the output of `grep --color=always ...`), so it may not cover all the escapes you expect.

According to the information on [this site](http://www.commandlinefu.com/commands/view/3584/remove-color-codes-special-characters-with-sed), the last character class could probably be shorten from `[a-zA-Z]` to just `[mK]`.

Answer (score 13):

The Perl module [`Term::ANSIColor`](http://perldoc.perl.org/Term/ANSIColor.html) provides a function, `colorstrip()`, to do just this.  For example,

```
ls --color | perl -MTerm::ANSIColor=colorstrip -ne 'print colorstrip($_)'
```

Module `Term::ANSIColor` is part of the Perl core.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out this is part of the Perl core library.