# Shell command execution from perl script contains garbage characters

Tags: perl

I have a perl script which runs a shell command and parses the output as shown below:

```
# Using ls -ltr for illustration. Actual command is different.
my $cmd = "ls -ltr 2>&1 | ";
open (CMD, $cmd ) || die "Cant run $cmd";

while (my $line = <CMD>) {
  chomp $line;
  ...
  ...
}
```

The above `$line` contains junk characters even after using `chomp`. I have tried redirecting the output to file and also reading from file but still even the file has junk/garbage characters in them.

The sample output of executing above command:

```
^[[H^[[Jtotal 12
drwx------ 2 root root 4096 Dec 19 15:30 tad4d
drwx------ 2 root root 4096 Jan  2 15:37 oup
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  137 Jan  9 06:25 alth.txt
```

In the above output, before `total 12`, there are some garbage characters present.

1. What may be the reason for the junk characters getting into the output of shell command?
2. How to avoid the garbage/junk characters?

Thanks

Comment: Going to need an example of "junk" to be able to answer.

Comment: Added a sample output!!

Comment: `^[` is an escape code. Do you have a prompt configured, especially one with colours? (`echo $PS1` should tell you)

Comment: `^[[H^[[J` is the garbage am getting

Answer (score 2):

1 - can't answer without knowing the command. If it's `ls` you shouldn't be parsing `ls`, but you indicate that you aren't. With the sample input you've given: `^[[H^[[J` - is an escape code, used for things like colours in terminals. See: [Control Sequences](https://www.gnu.org/software/screen/manual/html_node/Control-Sequences.html) -

This *probably* comes from your prompt. Check what `$PS1` is set to in your shell. But there's a workaround there that involves bypassing shell:

```
open ( my $output, '-|', 'ls', '-ltr' );
while ( <$output> ) { 
     print;
}
```

That way you won't involve the shell in the processing at all, so any 'junk' comes directly from the command you're running.

See: [perlfaq](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq8.html#How-can-I-call-backticks-without-shell-processing%3F)

2 - Fix the command to not generate "junk". I can't be more specific, because I don't know what you mean. But running it through a regex to filter out particular "junk" characters is quite doable. E.g. `s/[^\w\s]+//g` will filter out anything that *isn't* alphanumeric and whitespace. Although note - this will remove punctuation, but you can figure out a more suitable example by reading [`perlre`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html)

In your example though - because it's escape codes - you're not getting just control codes, but rather escape sequences. This is probably altogether more annoying to filter, because there's not a fixed length to them. But perhaps this will help: [Best way to remove ANSI color escapes in Unix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7394889/best-way-to-remove-ansi-color-escapes-in-unix)

I'd point out as a supplemental - 3 argument `open` using lexical filehandles is good practice, and avoids some gotchas.

Comment: Prompt isn't used when `-c` is used, so it's not from a prompt. Probably from a badly-written shell startup file. This is the sequence that is emitted by `clear`.

Answer (score 1):

You have configured your shell to call `clear` whenever it is launched. Those characters are emitted by `clear` to instruct your terminal to home the cursor and clear itself. You should limit calling `clear` to login shells and/or interactive shells.